# Upcasting in C++ : cannot convert child class pointer to parent class pointer

Tags: c++, casting, upcasting

I have a problem with my program. I made a Graph class in C++, and now I want to sort it topologically. The thing is, my topological sort accepts any DirectedGraph, but when I want to give it a child (AdjacencyListDirectedUnweightedGraph for example), it refuses to convert. Here is my .hpps:

TopoSort.hpp:

```
#ifndef TOPOSORT_HPP
#define TOPOSORT_HPP

#include "../Graph.hpp"
#include "../DirectedGraph/AdjListUWDG.hpp"
#include "../DirectedGraph/DirectedGraph.hpp"
#include "../UnDirectedGraph/AdjListWUDG.hpp"

class TopoSort
{
protected:
    std::vector<int> _sortedList;
    std::vector<int> _KahnTopNodes;
public:
    TopoSort();
    ~TopoSort();
    void KahnSort(DirectedGraph &list);
    void KahnSortTopNodes(DirectedGraph &list);
};

#endif
```

DirectedGraph.hpp

```
#ifndef DIRECTEDGRAPH_HPP
#define DIRECTEDGRAPH_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "../Graph.hpp"

class DirectedGraph
: public Graph
{
protected:
    std::vector<int> _inDegree;
    std::vector<int> _outDegree;
public:
    DirectedGraph(){};
    virtual ~DirectedGraph(){};
    int     inDegree(int a){return (_inDegree[a]);}
    int     outDegree(int a){return (_outDegree[a]);}
    bool    rangeCheck(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a >= _vertices || b >= _vertices || a == b)
        {
            std::cout << "The edge " << a << " - " << b << " is invalid." << std::endl;
            return (false);
        }
        return (true);

    }
};

#endif
```

AdjListDG.hpp

```
#ifndef ADJListDG_HPP
#define ADJListDG_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "DirectedGraph.hpp"

class AdjListDG
: public virtual DirectedGraph
{
protected:
    std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int, int> > > _adjList;
public:
    virtual ~AdjListDG();
    bool    existsEdge(Edge);
    bool    existsEdge(int, int);
    void    putEdge(Edge);
    void    removeEdge(Edge);
    int     adjacentVertices(int);
    bool    areAdjacent(int, int);
};

#endif
```

AdjListUWDG.hpp

```
#ifndef AdjListUWDG_HPP
#define AdjListUWDG_HPP

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include "AdjListDG.hpp"

class AdjListUWDG
: public virtual AdjListDG
{
public:
    AdjListUWDG(std::string);
    virtual ~AdjListUWDG();
};

#endif
```

And, my main.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include "UnDirectedGraph/AdjListWUDG.hpp"
#include "UnDirectedGraph/AdjListUWUDG.hpp"
#include "UnDirectedGraph/AdjMatWUDG.hpp"
#include "UnDirectedGraph/AdjMatUWUDG.hpp"
#include "Assgn3/TopoSort.hpp"


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage : ./graph FILENAME" << std::endl;
        return(0);
    }

    std::string filename = argv[1];
    AdjListWUDG gr(filename);
    TopoSort tsort;
    std::ofstream fichier("results.txt", std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    if(fichier)
    {
        if (gr.existsEdge(1, 2))
            fichier << "1 - 2 exist" << std::endl;
        fichier << "numedge == " << gr.numEdges() << std::endl;
        fichier << "adjver 1 == " << gr.adjacentVertices(1) << std::endl;
        fichier << "adj 1 2 == " << gr.areAdjacent(1,2) << std::endl;
        fichier << "adj 1 0 == " << gr.areAdjacent(1,0) << std::endl;
        fichier << "adj 0 2 == " << gr.areAdjacent(0,2) << std::endl;
    }    
    DirectedGraph * gr2 = &gr;
    tsort.KahnSort(*gr2);
}
```

That's it ! I'm sorry if it looks obvious or something, I just can't see what's the problem. Also tried dynamic and static casts, no success. thanks in advance !

EDIT :

I was stupid. tried to cast for a reference, instead of an object itself...

static_cast instead of static_cast

Sorry for that useless post !

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Answer (score 0):

Casting to a reference instead of the object itself, that was stupid, sorry !